# Why do i have to create a BizTalk Service to use a hybrid connection

Tags: .net, sql-server, azure, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to connect to an on-premises database from an azure hosted web API service. All instruction I have found states that I need to create a BizTalk service as well.

Does anyone know if that's correct?

Comment: You're misinterpreting. BizTalk offers hybrid connectivity. There's zero requirement to use BizTalk. And nothing stops you from just... connecting to your on-premises database, assuming your firewall allows incoming connections. As to a "better" way - that type of question is off-topic (tool/software recommendation, and opinion-soliciting).

Comment: Thanks David for your help. I guess the usage BizTalk just confused me a little. I can't mark your response as an answer because it is a comment,

Comment: The documentation around this is confusing.  At one point, the way to do this was to use BizTalk Azure Services in one of its many incarnations.  Since then, Hybrid Connections has been extrapolated a bit.

Comment: But yes, if you're going to use hybrid connections, you do need BizTalk services.  It's a bit confusing about how that will work going forward.  Docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-hybrid-connection-get-started.  As noted, you don't necessarily needt o use hybrid connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this out properly: BizTalk Services offers hybrid connectivity, but BizTalk is not a *requirement* for connecting to on-premises resources such as a database. There's nothing stopping you from connecting directly (provided your firewall can be configured to allow this).

If your firewall blocks incoming connections (e.g. to your database and related port), then you either need to open that port, whitelist an IP address, or use some type of software (vpn) to allow you entry into your on-prem network. And which software / service you choose is a matter of opinion and entirely up to you and your organization.